# Make system app remain uninstalled/disabled permanently

Tags: uninstallation, root-access, adb

I already know that I can uninstall an android system app using adb `pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.package.name`, which is quite useful but not enough.

There are some system apps that I have to continuously uninstall and reinstall for several reasons, and connecting my smartphone to the pc every time is something I would gladly avoid.

Is there any method (possibly apart from rooting my device) to prevent a disabled/uninstalled system app from being reinstalled?

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT:
As suggested by @Robert:

- Model name: Xiaomi Mi 9T Pro
- Android version: 10 (Q)
- MIUI version: 12.0.4
- Package name: com.google.android.youtube (mainly)

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add more details like your phone model, the installed Android version and the exact package names of the system app(s) you are talking about. Also some more information would be good on what occasions the apps are getting reactivated.

Comment: @Robert I updated my question

Comment: The Youtube app is most likely updated by Google Play Store. On modern devices Play Store updates Google  apps even if you have not registered with a Google account. If you have already disable auto update in Google Play Store settings I don't know if there are other options to prevent such an update besides deleting the app with root permissions.

Comment: @Robert the fact is that I don't just want to restore factory settings and prevent update... I want to be able to completely uninstall the application as I do using adb

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option. The solution is customer specific. On some phones the app stays disabled, on others it gets reactivated, because the OS decides its necessary. Its possible that some setting or some other app makes the disabled one necessary, which leads to its re-activation.

Comment: Thanks for your response... I updated my question with my phone specs. If it helps to solve the problem, let me know

Comment: The only way it can help is if one of us has the phone and can play with it. To debug the issue is not easy. People often don't understand how hard it is to find a problem and its solution, it takes countless hours sometimes. This package should be disabled from the play store, perhaps it has some permission or device administrator options that need to go first. Try from the play store or the system app safe removal app from the store.